# Given a starting, an ending date and a step how to create a sequence in awk?

Tags: linux, shell, date, unix, awk

I am new in awk and challenged by a timestamp issue. I would to create a sequence given a starting, an ending date and a step how to create a sequence in awk ?

For exemple given : **startime = 01-01-2014 :00:00:00**, **endtime = 01-01-2014 :00:45:00** by **15 mn** to have this sequence.

```
01-01-2014 :00:00:00
01-01-2014 :00:15:00
01-01-2014 :00:30:00
01-01-2014 :00:45:00
```

Comment: the `01-01-2004` is `MM-dd-yyyy` or `dd-MM-yyyy' ?

Comment: @Kent does it matter? (-:

Comment: @tripleee if start time is `01-01-2014 00:00:00`, endtime is `01-01-2015 00:00:00` step is `15mins`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert your input dates into a format suitable for [`mktime`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) the rest should be easy.

```
awk -v start="01-01-2014 :00:00:00" -v stop="01-01-2014 :00:45:00" '
    BEGIN { split(start, from, "[-: ]+"); split(stop, until, "[-: ]+");
        begin=mktime(from[3] " " from[2] " " from[1] " " 
                from[4] " " from[5] " " from[6]);
        end=mktime(until[3] " " until[2] " " until[1] " "
                until[4] " " until[5] " " until[6]); }
    END { for (i=begin; i<=end; i+=60*15) print strftime("%c", i) }' </dev/null
```

If you desire a different output format, change the first argument to `strftime` to something more suitable.  See the link to documentation above.

Comment: Sorry for the mess with the variable names.  Notice how `start` and `stop` are the human-readable input dates, `from` and `until` are arrays containing the split fields, and `begin` and `end` are the corresponding final Unix timestamps.  I should probably use something like `startstr` -> `startarray` -> `startepoch` instead.